# Selecting a dropdown option from a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following for loop. Which sees if the data value is in the dropdown if so it will show it as selected.

```
for (var i in data) {
    $("#optionDropdwon option:contains(data[i])").prop("selected", true);
    console.log(data[i])
}
```

It works fine when I replace `data[i]` in the `:contains()` with an actual string i.e "xyz"
but when I replace it with `data[i]` nothing happens. Yet I can see `console.log(data[i])` shows me the proper values. 
I searched Stackoverflow but couldn't find something like what I am doing.

Please let me know where I am making a mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must construct a proper selector for this to work. In your example, you have only the literal string `data[i]` in the selector, but not the actual value

```
$("#optionDropdwon option:contains(" + data[i] + ")").prop("selected", true);
```